# Mi paquete composer custom me ha empezado a dar error de buenas a primeras

Tags: laravel, composer, packages

me habia creado un paquete, el cual estaba trabajando con el, pero me dispuse a instalar un nuevo paquete el de **debugbar** tipico de laravel, y de pronto ahora no funciona mi paquete custom.

El paquete que he creado se llama : `josanangel/how_fast`

En el `composer.json` de la aplicacion laravel esta asi :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "josanangel/how_fast": "@dev",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "*",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "packages/josanangel/how_fast",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

El paquete lo tengo creado en `[raiz-proyecto]/packages/josanangel/how_fast`.
Para instalarlo como paquete lanzo el siguiente comando de composer :

```
 composer require josanangel/how_fast @dev
```

el `composer.json` del paquete `how_fast` es :

```
{
    "name": "josanangel/how_fast",
    "description": "Desc",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "jose",
            "email": "jose@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "josanangel\\how_fast\\": "packages/josanangel/how_fast/src"
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es la estructura de carpeta del paquete :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al instalarlo, como ya le he indicado que esta ahi lo instala bien, si miramos en el vendor del proyecto ahi esta :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Peero con cualquier comando que lanzo me indica este error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Class "josanangel\how_fast\HowFastServiceProvider" not found
```

Tambien esta metido en el `config/app.php` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Reitero que esto ha sucedido tras instalar otro paquete, no se que ha pasado que ha dejado de funcionar el mio, tambien probe a desintalar el paquete problematico pero sigue sin ir y no hay manera de que vuelva a funcionar, estoy seguro que tiene que ser una chorrada porque no he tocado nada realmente, simplemente dejo de funcionar.

Otra cosa que probe es lanzar `composer dump-autoload` , tambien borre manualmente las carpetas `bootstrap/cache` pero nada funciona.

PD: Tambien probe a ponerle `\josanangel\...` pero nada :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]